# Python: What is wrong with my Miller-Rabin implementation?

Tags: python, key, rsa, primes

at the moment I try to implement a Miller-Rabin-Test from the algorithm shown in NIST FIPS186-4 Appendix C.3.1.

But at the moment the results of my both primes seems not to be perfect, because, for example during all my tests of my code:

```
>>> n,e,d = generating_Pairs()
>>> message = 1234567890
>>> cipher = pow(message, e, n)
>>> plain = pow(cipher, d, n)
>>> plain == message
False
```

(The plain is always a very large int, larger than the original message)

My generating_keys()-function:

```
def generating_Pairs():
    p, q = gen_Random_Primes()
    n = p*q
    e = 65537
    phi = (p-1)*(q-1)
    d = inverse(e, phi)
    return(n,e,d)
```

The inverse-function for calculating d:

```
def inverse(e,phi):
    a, b, u = 0, phi, 1
    while(e > 0):
        q = b // e
        e, a, b, u = b%e, u, e, a-q*u
    if(b == 1):
        return a%phi
    else:
        print("Must be co-prime!")
```

My generating_keys()-function seems to be correct, because if I use provable primes (for example p = 13th mersenne prime and q = 14th mersenne prime, see [here](https://www.mersenne.org/primes/)) the result of the abovementioned test will be `True`. I think there is a mistake in my is_prime()-function, which is based on the Miller-Rabin-Test...

```
from random import randrange
def is_prime(w):
    iteration = 5 #p and q should be 1024 bits => 4 iterations are minimum?

    m = w - 1
    a = 0
    while not(m & 1):
        a += 1
        m >>= 1

    for _ in range(iteration):
        b = randrange(2, w-1)

        while((b <= 1) or b >= w - 1):
            b = randrange(2, w - 1)

        z = power(b, m, w) #see ANN1

        for _ in range(a):
            z = power(z, 2, w) #see ANN1
            if z == 1:
                return False
            if z == w - 1:
                break
    return True
```

ANN1: I am using a the power()-function instead of math.pow() (edit3: sorry, built_in pow(x,y [,z]), which is (x**y)%z), because the code should run on a special system with a special python-version (because of system constraints), without pow(a,b,c)...

Maybe this special power-function will be the problem, but I think there is a mistake in my is_prime(), which is the core function of my gen_Random_Primes()-function, but which seems to return True for p and q which are not really primes? And that is the reason for plain == message => False?

But here is my power() because for completeness:

```
def power(x, y, p):
    res = 1
    x = x%p
    while(y > 0):
        if((y & 1) == 1):
            res = (res*x)%p
        y >>= 1
        x = (x*x)%p
    return res
```

edit:
My nlen should be 2048bits long -> the sizes of p and q are 1024bit (very large primes)

edit2: A little mistake - forgot the return res in my power()-function. But in my implemtation the power()-function has a return res, so this will not be the problem ;)

edit3: sorry, built_in pow(x,y [,z]), which is (x**y)%z, instead of math.pow

edit4:
here some examples:

n = p*q

phi = (p-1)*(q-1)

private_key (for cipher) = (n,e)

public_key (for plain) = (n,d)

EXAMPLE01:################################

```
p = 153278952386343112861516138830439219958131262572001989611076268355877848523058709999207700485605081468914077929037769261015479227525227452449401011101469723675635614611092243738208719355456013217253135422472477856387471970992716603913394664778594230349851796850845021412801902220705133996887380661818440848317
q = 158966122079667347252293835902427484318353919446383834628309005881872697109397189566089924423596952117031809401859037909351997179049071188790410033650716934063577007590353013796258148845763088248887460202831932907380675412089905177507426652619387129610421611581422746450658896507905016224327948291632998343971
n = 24366160657290937939234153324343152502384001817946624551571122400737379061841645065858899053151158734817070297897852413751169971231673481393316697538906604107269462569082519609906808338138946759303889661330461376990256707586724059857880457741622527522854931069740149809256897665830716836184526115719344743761645933212802480825580807727572342401134038022443167933343106415985609631284326431505534429375684115406275044088979620133778715752680969930614074574261604921123707141539217485547590077450015016094835309620895392345723905466518271070269383228113160497332527751169556561591967414267378951017113422700881402446807
e = 65537
d = 17274963589733526716336965379286208368872091497460548440792233871368258857277723977906646407458617871653269974541492814021611632258243078558052200046504363233595805557316480631623509507961731880072263442392214434906622025135565355711072487121881519123883173127003163415129049134765986039587985739975641762273625715026010738347209341037702876219216462993080200129963155150986046425007682872210677371297597135201485785733365271854554523780116581088384970026628097260935000890283507771219338034919756067218634835147949087816408934549777286243756344974891589231104024074659282336875373169116580764456423226999719026086913
phi = 24366160657290937939234153324343152502384001817946624551571122400737379061841645065858899053151158734817070297897852413751169971231673481393316697538906604107269462569082519609906808338138946759303889661330461376990256707586724059857880457741622527522854931069740149809256897665830716836184526115719344743761333688138336470365466997752839475696857552840424782109103721141747859085651870531940236804466482081820329156758082812963411239346106671289374263529509418263384494519337772228013123209248795914628694713995590981581955758083435649288848561910715179137372254342737288793728506615538768800795898093747429963254520
```

d should be correct, because for this e, d, phi:

```
>>> (e*d)%phi
1
```

But if you try to enrypt (make a cipher) and decrypt (undo cipher = plain):

```
message = 1234567890
cipher = power(message,e,d) #same as (message**e)%n
plain = power(cipher,d,n) #same as (cipher**d)%n
```

you will get:

```
>>> cipher
7582453483123782316642815207511509460123690813093883757865778590854769823444496048630408532746966392966067010239879640641437430367798732703096575691828231449246792228610248734149965734608561945416563715359518516936192024799846436629865250108369647161886815833543979311512965674758113118505287260490159638736268299024213305764769094191211776578538139794602124749434951864660928435041738055064357946181468209321671158821420411181701738699381970454853036275026924447113637686219886313455880197010339064148710566050312637252815539387371754036905714481567541746525837880619907843263703714528916056846821658479428821702799
>>> plain
2506678376199532577786495780354166644277263701374427104991286855439327130392426627706898765559799754136604242869092325064170490643931920526072098326334198460034536727890580557834435895613875615739892723160337739471263384445704979849989265751741515657006179133998272575884880354970790040910244055405007280150155944497462791854983809250394636024022408598995890385001669873486898335192266131038117960572422303140608246905882204766339115796505409973933273130830998154966651370106471194424674487944304554404244102371812455992949145041295591557402607650756918969076755549087347227152938532676219564672872091841940439906823
```

You can see, that plain is really not the message

```
>>> plain == message
False
```

Let us do a second example/test:
EXAMPLE02:################################

```
p = 151000448093392138083909177508717203782700741053411977445583547285229153941286337902970666747751598140351035034315356744660640075753463317248127809201201802296279357953239911683665525006800637881313365848486482728096475210446711456467971189292271259825826843971960795144891542895179717280616703652603696895339
q = 148124081383037385391596445248642476004227433435914930913672983646671819235598185424883742197429805844229078255522368361277189556916061601257602591774692685590328750660480818820825397887875014126153510363701871517734836225506065854979355008918136143153161859316761084109149508825851534915899190860012402769611
n = 22366802662260729456956546861488601785938913818506251235759151149363682764610849516896735266633778507381353192212960524484748058148902933375123262193745059835162873665089513061671612181140260714274706430714782809143277901597258645771925028254527786781501499561033344017516390704013770385331368297897961727978672607036696365234991950076062643187019813666393837322094177790596953768668362465889675915765533974409142859879746884071641242665207372602490990036696997084431295929304332268428662030606250672882177696411638288639368218633089155494361214849267709296282062361317108880055193474754723123085711234419765596743129
e = 65537
d = 13160636651999607081788277767867364421157153892751240675547315052897788039869441370074490827348395056252799819920292105912398410338251597064429303091615377532745635812948133156601320001360006311913289124940468051424128087056067380231883866206129369880651552955926695027289425184677037606224700921670830220399194931602658271829767873582989125877075766823913540909325206121964749163064259462915131314311098094522361240734242900774149793450428376068325367076196303741824560961616664817209086260518085294642272283573114246457475475156567633786861244398768202322498025945662612867920320425668328210403728438858957518750153
phi = 22366802662260729456956546861488601785938913818506251235759151149363682764610849516896735266633778507381353192212960524484748058148902933375123262193745059835162873665089513061671612181140260714274706430714782809143277901597258645771925028254527786781501499561033344017516390704013770385331368297897961727978373482507219935711516444453305283507232885491904510413734921259665052795491477942561821506820352570424562746589909158965703413032537847683985259635721102596544687820690611537924171107711575020874710820199449934393536907197136378182913888651057301893303073658028387000801152423033691870889195339907149497078180
```

check the condition for d:

```
>>>(e*d)%phi
1
```

Let us do the encrypt/decrypt for this example:

```
message = 1234567890
cipher = power(message,e,d) #same as (message**e)%n
plain = power(cipher,d,n) #same as (cipher**d)%n
```

You will get:

```
>>> cipher
19582650241671478797736206916151785806793342503887934233292468043928447391216953542528369245042791835732418321140061279441359508294343645916954129769216400129961217152361034874685568300192215242498114226028794719265275556964675603955948790756025759486815304457849055836050730644761707261720362010091500167797282697580948292001704212203516725864235377985907325375001695044383613281561738586886478940910401509320095813715935744827291447691109873641774308205509624953961383224998370369115523043565414869676711449349616974080539090276559658054844048940327159272094930135679435668895885597768311656233633134501875799959945

>>> plain
6083429875214510719927083766713233744592420986316684568290880389711253208169504107321709423820282968116179978192210334710968013237588326260985224812182914293551878626127025285184924521033808922383038422073726589474061901614923932303292881343735655246200763492872615982118360880481263715561005747379043420630222303011824240141556291702645175779056516254627164942441440790263320061469776092449625855913049066614886658724425305130815980340969759725366834527202832142658592646993117009538926737701618299240707475862947345174017146739190658346668982366958034902005777118294631852412541490729616655104422311467398220120569
>>> plain == message
False
```

Now, we will test everything with PROVABLE PRIMES, I selected for p = 13th mersenne prime and for q = 14th mersenne prime:

EXAMPLE03:######With#MERSENNE#PRIMES########

```
p = 6864797660130609714981900799081393217269435300143305409394463459185543183397656052122559640661454554977296311391480858037121987999716643812574028291115057151
q = 531137992816767098689588206552468627329593117727031923199444138200403559860852242739162502265229285668889329486246501015346579337652707239409519978766587351943831270835393219031728127
n = 3646154850295011369707131011438711095400799139943170490872585628683549034362552065955809589514611470241298944167703929337528884908857116141935206466329731087514964112054543019336536216107629523597606330154669196064144182472739556974502462402438903115845725630946428943768540714098264727068026730424033578827886916761701429264950573899186177
e = 65537
d = 605309440029444797632079365922351903778944636504290628815687804447518401725202045830587428993072200378798732205389608178468869002370652053408838463061590768976059755211666722868590174546762165023955171158423681809701058604934000382033836393559131564093520170601086332978178762009136501271874027235396379522707933355224417396404416034089473
phi = 3646154850295011369707131011438711095400799139943170490872585628683549034362552065955809589514611470241298944167703929337528884908857116141935206466329731086983826119237775920646948002690363236137403497445736473783306827002900696970344810268812941665073256564401047334962399037297130412119008099533655562939311565101226345855529063752400900

>>> (e*d)%phi
1

>>> message = 1234567890
>>> cipher = pow(message, e, n)
>>> plain = pow(cipher, d, n)
>>> cipher = 3527787294202495847516460093960040111155862778590101142852928060146217450670864190293138429578667938663819181298161737329079067252663099780485504380443854855906571037888470692628813913848572749600751040887103649399418365664020425441281586512839896401702197649288926423242264498276766744058040547340187336760773966010060700622351934331652019
>>> plain
1234567890
>>> plain == message
True
```

Now, let us try the 16th and 17th Mersenne Prime:
EXAMPLE04:######With#MERSENNE#PRIMES########

```
p = 1475979915214180235084898622737381736312066145333169775147771216478570297878078949377407337049389289382748507531496480477281264838760259191814463365330269540496961201113430156902396093989090226259326935025281409614983499388222831448598601834318536230923772641390209490231836446899608210795482963763094236630945410832793769905399982457186322944729636418890623372171723742105636440368218459649632948538696905872650486914434637457507280441823676813517852099348660847172579408422316678097670224011990280170474894487426924742108823536808485072502240519452587542875349976558572670229633962575212637477897785501552646522609988869914013540483809865681250419497686697771007
q = 446087557183758429571151706402101809886208632412859901111991219963404685792820473369112545269003989026153245931124316702395758705693679364790903497461147071065254193353938124978226307947312410798874869040070279328428810311754844108094878252494866760969586998128982645877596028979171536962503068429617331702184750324583009171832104916050157628886606372145501702225925125224076829605427173573964812995250569412480720738476855293681666712844831190877620606786663862190240118570736831901886479225810414714078935386562497968178729127629594924411960961386713946279899275006954917139758796061223803393537381034666494402951052059047968693255388647930440925104186817009640171764133172418132836351
n = 658416274830184544125027519921443515789888264156074733099244040126213682497714032798116399288176502462829255784525977722903018714434309698108208388664768262754316426220651576623731617882923164117579624827261244506084274371250277849351631679441171018418018498039996472549893150577189302871520311715179730714312181456245097848491669795997289830612988058523968384808822828370900198489249243399165125219244753790779764466236965135793576516193213175061401667388622228362042717054014679032953441034021506856017081062617572351195418505899388715709795992029559042119783423597324707100694064675909238717573058764118893225111602703838080618565401139902143069901117174204252871948846864436771808616432457102844534843857198735242005309073939051433790946726672234643259349535186268571629077937597838801337973092285608744209951533199868228040004432132597073390363357892379997655878857696334892216345070227646749851381208554044940444182864026513709449823489593439017366358869648168238735087593808344484365136284219725233811605331815007424582890821887260682886632543613109252862114326372077785369292570900594814481097443781269562647303671428895764224084402259605109600363098950091998891375812839523613295667253813978434879172781217285652895469194181218343078754501694746598738215243769747956572555989594598180639098344891175879455994652382137038240166358066403475457
e = 65537
d = 334105797271047151981657921517730832371157119074330856217838164677012408641591434986864808806133905517552676051241221220880766442883064579097099015417787407817836444609823288099833966832697449469677098482618977788033303759560236815204203169682707224751050905150039255552119361819964408750709972784839359821706301883041441842767276053766359012570998533260190313947880006413211727740947447067803460706031761174087490228255436052244551636823801781434029233115278710139434099796272520346062523994498058074121550388611165999532399069719243650604162160473244358221089118134071294983607455557349857985437381055885040711267092779938648535194027500626908005136511478177771620221295598221446655310402436746479782368967943153830391704773757455773861050160452401746790867834196061076588076120390140624579927639175546078677218011249954865423538080035612379874054142000812190387918675139826088813202731055651051339403348440263931094983603857618923283552638290258967144154247536313936995282079495778654678503630914818879103007330530120178133686334123351627296777405788745594506415615850210810277691545772909988881340556599596733717401089924014874029987229222036914331526326518454684517757259862612246129598984572912870240390422205211578326598705764422502804258285510188982398306082836846344931332983589484880260309348373229531127293270115611985532798401007828666273
phi = 658416274830184544125027519921443515789888264156074733099244040126213682497714032798116399288176502462829255784525977722903018714434309698108208388664768262754316426220651576623731617882923164117579624827261244506084274371250277849351631679441171018418018498039996472549893150577189302871520311715179730714312181456245097848491669795997289830612988058523968384808822828370900198489249243399165125219244753790779764466236965135793576516193213175061401667388622228362042717054014679032953441034021506856017081062617572351195418505899388715709795992029559042119783423597324707100694064675909238717573058764118893225111602703838080618565401139902143069901117174204252425861289680678342237463250075085820468400139887252603511581541909501414828351105531905619420047668081165948290616571506153659883771881424337363431225547368543782032187128677349306585454844368150965884442693427916237146706380358257245358145214299061139408586133209549295622870737780511845373058603583936928339541786261572218296400422758734811155093559687048536034020967026764962657833198315402334230423388741137414997867176910007275117765698155754484533236565743028710587661566079042375948557880113061241858319026329565154396064729731627098176102570966530887923691946706848615777083090494384632530604575140678340984026032761127934737187086971865040338267351562631185225613687961572868100

>>> (e*d)%phi
1

>>> message = 1234567890
>>> cipher = pow(message,e,n)
>>> plain = pow(cipher, d, n)
>>> cipher
456496826841733818270908304227082534081859737180166510716990603132608133299963062844944786777938246804747496862456284894415366813194701218076961537835930553236745171872139138552898222394380765429166665742337940993686632252985322797309711325449549577191721762092413669164574241208448333134863611775084360543326165001966810743638879340579077493555817807387986451299284100432323322095153193449738193340108996694653981343445907983610632925597419613278322234744442449149930389311418971374507078200795440203783866232507259920822701780626503271754241968747737872417441310189834826470519491444045650181872335299997179988923371195644750576072775817545165334288973701662021461240508380472416824025292141690571188682108619540733596998435122284415140172156977758375901535805389682026731937835429566482533381626946335892833187432334537467818988885690429477550078258412841917692854031969688551447316422564794103804701585262790167250552817617448061370437388807571786103338095535567011877750990827996996417785181236658050169690842830828818599786537294982837492884162936742016732057934481057205481007314702736519071184122573456680456466562972389492586174454504500146300230874944272253606674382312704016456597366616746992611807755165400937216085911729178600772950585314217787447205381014069794060332031079240858890492033777407635220177169518825659433065938177036758094
>>> plain
1234567890
>>> plain == message
True
```

I hope this are enough examples for the moment.

And the power()-function works fine, because for every pow(a,b,c) == power(a,b,c) is alway `True`

And you can see, that d is always calculating correct ((e*d)%phi == 1, is always True)

I guess my is_prime() is not correct...

Comment: Your power function has no return statement.

Comment: I forgot the return statement here - but in my implementation there is the return statement ;) But many thx for this

Comment: What does your power function actually do?  You say you are using it instead of math.pow, but math.pow takes two variables and your function takes three.

Comment: sorry, built_in pow(x,y [,z]), which is (x ** y)%z, instead of math.pow. so, power should do (x ** y)%z (faster than (x ** y)%z can do)

Comment: You could at least include some sample inputs and outputs that don't appear to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going to read all of that; it's too much work. But here is my Miller-Rabin prime checker:

```
def isPrime(n, k=5): # miller-rabin
    from random import randint
    if n < 2: return False
    for p in [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29]:
        if n % p == 0: return n == p
    s, d = 0, n-1
    while d % 2 == 0:
        s, d = s+1, d/2
    for i in range(k):
        x = pow(randint(2, n-1), d, n)
        if x == 1 or x == n-1: continue
        for r in range(1, s):
            x = (x * x) % n
            if x == 1: return False
            if x == n-1: break
        else: return False
    return True
```

I perform trial division on the first ten primes, which eliminates a large percentage of candidates, then perform five strong-pseudoprime checks on random bases.

Comment: thx for this - but I got many other Miller-Rabin implementation in python like this... what I want to do (or to find) is an implementation which is really NIST conformable - the algorithm is described here: https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/fips/nist.fips.186-4.pdf (see Appendix C.3.1). I need an implementation which is exactly an implementation of the process described in the NIST paper... :/

Comment: Sorry... after a second comparison it looks better and better... but I think instead of "d/2" in the first while loop, "d >>= 1" should be faster...

Comment: I doubt that d>>1 is faster than d/2. In the first place, we're working with Python bigints, not native integers, so the concept of shifting bits is . . . different. In the second place, the calculation you mention is not in the inner loop of the program, so it is doubtful that it will make any difference to the efficiency of the overall function. What measurements did you make to justify your prejudice that shifting is faster than division?

Comment: 1. I found my mistake in my abovementioned Miller-Rabin-Test: "        else: return False" after "for _ in range(a):"-loop was missing... thx for this :) +1 .... 2. no idea, read it anywhere... it seems to depend on your cpu, the compiler and so on... but if in Python there is no difference, thank you for this information ;) it is one of my habits to use this in every language (I guess there is no language in which d>>1 is slower than d/2) ;)

Comment: d/2 produces a float in python3. d//2 produces an int in both 2 and 3.